# Нет перевода для "Сохранить изменение меток"

Tags: дефект, локализация, метки

Заметил что нет перевода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

подобных вопросов не нашел. Посмотрел в traducir:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если норм то можно взять [такую](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/2954) строку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но будет немного не то по смыслу как мне кажется.

Comment: Строка "Save Tag Edits" числится удаленной с 2021-09-16... Видать какая-то проблема есть в SO или в Transifex, раз такое стало выплывать.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, может тогда стоит добавить как-то?

Comment: я так понял что я добавить ничего не могу, правильно?

Comment: Строки мы не можем сами добавить, они добавляются только автоматически на основе того, что разработчики добавляют в локализованные ресурсы SO. Тут для начала можно просто подождать, возможно данные еще не обновились, и со временем строка либо разудалиться, либо вместо нее появится новая. Если за сутки само не исправится, следующим шагом будет посмотреть историю в Transifex и выяснить, действительно ли строка удалена и почему. У alexolut и Николаса должен быть доступ.

Comment: Дело в том что я это наблюдаю уже дней пять, так что проблема давно висит)

Comment: Уже написал об этом на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370052/339911)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, спасибо большое

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблему пофиксили [по-тихому](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371464/339911). Старый перевод вернулся в строй.

Comment: гуд, спасибо за содействие :)